# Rewrite C++ code for use wrapper class pointer instead raw pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, url-rewriting, wrapper

In a started project, I would to start using my own wrapper class pointer instead of raw pointers.
My idea was rewrite the existent code for translate declarations like "Object *a" to "MyPointerObject a", but this rewrite does not seems trivial.

What is the simplest way to perform this?

I've looked clang, elsa, gccxml and doxygen, but none of these tools seems to be either simple enough or powerful enough for my task.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  If you're going to move away from raw pointers, why not consider existing smart pointers (e.g. `boost::shared_ptr`).

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth, I want add some additional logic, not just wrap my pointer into a smart pointers. (Anyway, my problem will persist, right?)

Comment: I agree, you'll still need to replace all instances.

Comment: gccxml would seem powerful enough, and whether it's simple enough depends on whether you've really got enough existing code to make it a net win time wise....  I've not heard of anything much better.

Comment: How much code have you got? How many different types do you have that will need wrapping? I'd probably reach first for a regular expression replace script - hard in general, but ok if you know your own coding style.

Comment: @TonyDelroy gccxml it's ok for find declarations, but has no utilities for rewrite code

Comment: Does it not log the file, line and column where the declarations exist?

Comment: @TonyDelroy this is the "easy part". But then you need rewrite the expressions, not hard but not straightforward. You still need to parse statements like "O a, **b, *c;"  (although these cases are very rare in the code)

Comment: So, parse and auto-fix the easy ones, print out a list of the very rare weird ones for manual correction.  Your tool doesn't have to do all the work, it needs to break the back of the beast and let you get the job done.